# Empty ArrayList.size() returns 0 when initialized with a length

Tags: java, string, split

I have a Text class that I made on my own, which splits a string in a list of Sentence (which is basically a list of list of characters).
I had the previous code before that worked perfectly:

```
private List<Sentence> content;

public Text(String content) {
    this.content = new ArrayList<Sentence>();
    for (String s : content.split("([.!?:]=;)")){
        this.content.add(new Sentence(s));
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to instantiate content by giving it the length of the array returned by `content.split("([.!?:]=;)")`. The code now looks like this:

```
    private List<Sentence> content;
    public Text(String content) {
    this.content = new ArrayList<Sentence>(content.split("([.!?:]=;)").length);
    System.out.println(this.content.size());
    for (String s : content.split("([.!?:]=;)")){
        this.content.add(new Sentence(s));
    }
```

And the result of the console print returns me 0. I don't understand why. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Can you share an string example that you try to split ?

Comment: The string I use are pretty big, but I can :
Les Rougon-Macquart doivent se composer d’une vingtaine de romans. Depuis 1869, le plan général est arrêté, et je le suis avec une rigueur extrême. L’Assommoir est venu à son heure, je l’ai écrit, comme j’écrirai les autres, sans me déranger une seconde de ma ligne droite.

Comment: [The Capacity of an ArrayList vs the Size of an Array in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-capacity-array-size)

Comment: But the full strings I use looks like this : https://www.file.io/download/6MHh6ixOzlS0 (these are very big string so I must upload them as files)

Comment: Your regex is wrong. Update to `([.!?:])`. The `=;` part matches the characters `=;` literally.

Comment: I don't know well regex but what I would like to select characters after a character . ! ? :, and I don't know how to do it

Comment: Everyone, errors in the regex are not the point here. Splitting a long string by a regex that fails to match anything will give an array of length 1, not 0. So while your regex comments are probably helpful, they do not contribute to answering the question.